# Murray-von Neumann equivalence of projections is a transitive relation

Tags: c-star-algebras, projection

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra and $p,q \in A$ projections. We say that  $p$ and $q$ are Murray - von Neumann equivalent, written $p \sim q$, if there is $u \in A$ with $p = uu^*$ and $q=u^*u$. I'm trying to show that
$$p \sim q, \quad q \sim r \implies p \sim r$$

There are $u,v \in A$ with
$$p = uu^*, q = u^* u = vv^* , r = v^* v$$

I want to find/construct $w \in A$ with
$$p = ww^*, r = w^*w$$

How can I define $w$?

I feel like this should be simple. I must be missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$u$ in the definition of Murray-von Neumann equivalence can't just be some arbitrary element of $A$; there are conditions imposed on it by the condition that $p$ and $q$ are projections. We have

$$p^2 = u u^{\ast} u u^{\ast} = p = u u^{\ast} = uqu^{\ast}$$
$$q^2 = u^{\ast} u u^{\ast} u = q = u^{\ast} u = u^{\ast} pu$$

Now we can set $w = uv$ (which doesn't obviously work!), which gives

$$ww^{\ast} = uv v^{\ast} u^{\ast} = uqu^{\ast} = uu^{\ast} = p$$
$$w^{\ast}w = v^{\ast} u^{\ast} u v = v^{\ast} qv = v^{\ast}v = r$$

as desired.

This is maybe still a bit too obscure so here is what is going on geometrically in the case $A = M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Then you can check that the condition that $P = X X^{\ast}$ for $P$ a projection matrix and $X$ a matrix means that the singular values of $X$ are equal to either $1$ or $0$ and that for the nonzero singular values $\sigma_1 = \dots = \sigma_k = 1$, the corresponding left singular vectors $u_1, \dots u_k$ of $X$ have the property that $\text{span}(u_1, \dots u_k) = \text{im}(P)$. Similarly the condition that $Q = X^{\ast} X$ says that the singular values of $X$ are equal to either $1$ or $0$ and the right singular vectors $v_1, \dots v_k$ have the property that $\text{span}(v_1, \dots v_k) = \text{im}(Q)$. So $X$ is a partial isometry from $\text{im}(Q)$ to $\text{im}(P)$ such that $X^{\ast}$ is a partial isometry the other way around, and that's why composing works. This also explains the identities above.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. This really helped!

Comment: According to your 8-th line, why does that operator fix q? Moreover the Mourray von neumann relation work in arbitrary ring. Two idempotent are equivalent if e=xy f=yx. There is a nice trick to prove the transitive property but I always forget it.(here x,y are arbitrary)

Comment: @AliTaghavi In the 8th (5th?) line, it doesn't. I have edited it out.